# Why does my solution work and this other solution doesnt?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

If you notice the result of the for loop that is starting at index 0 and counting up isn't taking the number 23 out fo the array.

Using JavaScript Loop through evenArray removing all values that aren't even

```
var evenArray = [1,2,3,6,22,98,45,23,22,12];
for (var i = evenArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if(evenArray[i] % 2 != 0){
    evenArray.splice(i, 1);
   }
 };
 console.log(evenArray);
```

//output to this will be 2, 6, 22, 98, 22, 12;

```
var evenArray = [1,2,3,6,22,98,45,23,22,12];
for (var i = 0; i < evenArray.length; i++) {
    if(evenArray[i] % 2 != 0){
        evenArray.splice(i, 1);
    }
};

console.log(evenArray);
```

//output is [2, 6, 22, 98, 23, 22, 12];

Comment: Just debug it and you will see. Run through each of those for loops, pausing after the splice each time. You will see what's going on.

Comment: Awesome! That's a great idea. I need to get used to dissecting my code with a Debugger.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you `splice` a number out of the array, all of the values after that point in the array get shifted to the left.

In the second approach, at index 6 the value is `45`. You detect it as odd, so you splice. Now the 23, 22, and 12 get shifted over so that 23 is now at index 6. But since you are iterating forward, your `i++` moves you up to index 7, effectively skipping the 23, which is why 23 is in the result.

When you iterate backwards, you avoid this problem because all of the numbers being shifted have already been acted on.

Comment: That being said, adding `i--;` after the splice in the second snippet should correct the problem for that one, right? Edit: or even changing the splice line to `evenArray.splice(i--, 1);`

Comment: @JosephMarikle yeah that would correct the 'drift' issue

Answer (score 3):

Dylan's answer is correct explaining why one works and the other fails.

Regardless, a simple solution that will work is:

```js
var evenArray = [1,2,3,6,22,98,45,23,22,12];

evenArray = evenArray.filter(function(val) { return val % 2 == 0; });

console.log(evenArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding one single print into the code:

```
var evenArray = [1,2,3,6,22,98,45,23,22,12];
for (var i = 0; i < evenArray.length; i++) {
    console.log("index:"+i+" value:"+evenArray[i])
    if(evenArray[i] % 2 != 0){
        evenArray.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

The output like this:

```
index:0 value:1
index:1 value:3
index:2 value:22
index:3 value:98
index:4 value:45
index:5 value:22
index:6 value:12
```

Compare to the origin array, it's cutting.
The reason is `splice` is cutting your array dynamically, so the index is changed after splice, value `23` origin index is `7`, but after the splice it move to before index `6`

```
[1,2,3,6,22,98,45,23,22,12];
```